# Streaming a video UDP protocol

Tags: c, opencv, udp, h.264

I'm creating a program to stream a video (UDP protocol) and edit the stream with OpenCV. On the receiving side I would like to open the UDP stream with a C code (using OpenCV functions). The image format is IPLImage. How do i extract the data from the UDP stream? The stream is sent after H.264 encoding. Also how do i encode a video in H264 in C code?

Answer (score 0):

To stream the video over UDP, you probably want to use [RTP](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1889.html). To extract data from the stream, you basically strip off the RTP and UDP headers.

There are a few libraries that support h.264 encoding. Quite a bit of the choice tends to based on the platform(s) you need to support. Just for example, on Windows you might want to use the Windows Media Foundation (WMF) h.264 codec, but Windows is the *only* place you can use that.